# Bring down words from theorem

Tags: formatting

I have a theorem that goes like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{definition}[Integers]
Integers are positive and negative whole numbers, including 0.\\
e.g. $..., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...$
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image: definition]

How do I make the statement "Integers are positive and negative..." come down 1 line?

I have tried \\ but that will create a no line to end error and does not bring down the "Integers are positive and negative..." either.

Thank you!

Comment: you haven't shown enough information, in particular which theorem package you are using (if any) `theorem` package has a `break` style that adds a linebreak

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{book} 


\begin{document}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{definition}[Integers]\\
Integers are positive and negative whole numbers, including 0.\\
e.g. $..., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...$
\end{definition}


\end{document}

Comment: There isn't any package that I'm using actually, this was the original code to generate that picture.

Comment: Please add it to the question, not as a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `amsthm` and define your own theorem styles.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}

\newtheoremstyle{breakthm}
  {\topsep}%   Space above
  {\topsep}%   Space below
  {\itshape}%  Body font
  {}%          Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%         Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}%  Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
  {}%          Thm head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
\newtheoremstyle{breakdef}
  {\topsep}%   Space above
  {\topsep}%   Space below
  {\upshape}%  Body font
  {}%          Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%         Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}%  Space after thm head: " " = normal interword space;
  {}%          Thm head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{breakthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{breakdef}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Integers]
Integers are positive and negative whole numbers, including $0$,
e.g.
\[
\dots, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,\dotsc
\]
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
The integers are useful.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In my opinion this is just a waste of space, though.

Note that `amsthm` provides for much better customization possibilities. With `theorem` (or, better, `ntheorem`) you have to define a new theorem style if you want to have the body font in definitions upright, which is customary.

Another possibility is to use `thmtools`, that makes defining new theorem styles quite easy. The same as before can be obtained with

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  postheadspace=\newline,
  bodyfont=\itshape,
]{breakthm}% main style

\declaretheoremstyle[
  style=breakthm,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
]{breakdef}% override the bodyfont

\declaretheorem[
  name=Theorem,
  style=breakthm,
  numberwithin=section,
]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[
  name=Definition,
  style=breakdef,
  numberlike=theorem,
]{definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[Integers]
Integers are positive and negative whole numbers, including $0$,
e.g.
\[
\dots, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,\dotsc
\]
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
The integers are useful.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many packages for customising theorems, including `theorem` in the core latex distribution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
 \begin{document} 
 \begin{definition}[Integers]
 Integers are positive and negative whole numbers, including 0.\\
e.g. $..., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...$ 
\end{definition}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `ntheorem`.

Comment: definitions are usually considered better set with roman (upright) text.